# Adding opacity hover effect to thumbnail with fancybox effect

Tags: html, css, fancybox

I'm attempting to add a opacity hover-over effect with small text to a thumbnail with a fancybox effect. I don't know much jquery so a css method would be preferable.

I found another forum that says to add a class of fade to my img element with the css of:

```
.fade {
   opacity: 1;
   transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;}

      .fade:hover {
       opacity: 0.5;}
```

But that had no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: JSfiddle example would be helpful as well as a visual reference if you have one.

Comment: Working fine for me - [TRY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b4hne6yt/)

Answer (score 2):

Your css is correct. If it is not working for you, you either did not apply the classname `fade` to your image(s), or you have a browser that does not support the `opacity` css property.

As @MaryMelody posted in a comment, this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4hne6yt/) has your code with the class applied to a div (the class can be applied to any element to make it fade on hover).